# how to calculate user ranking from 2 different tables

Tags: mysql

I have a `users` table with phase1 and phase2 columns that i need to calculate the users rank in each phase and store it in these fields.

the ranking is calculated based on a different table `points` where i have the points by phase for each user.

what i am trying to do is

1. sum all points for each user by phase and calculate his rank based on that
2. in case the user points are equal compare the sum of grade1 in case that is also equal compare the sum of grade2
3. update `users` table with his rank in each phase

here is how my new table look like with some demo data 
[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/65c0a1/1)

currently I use the below code to calculate the ranking from my old table where both rank and user info are in the same table

[old sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63ebce2/1)

```
update users a
join (
  select id,
  (
      select count(distinct total) 
      from users d
      where c.total < d.total
  ) +1 rank
  from users c
) b on a.id = b.id
set a.rank = b.rank
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are analytics function in oracle called as rank() and dense_rank() which can be useful to get your result.

As you are using mysql, I tried to convert those function in mysql equivalent.
You can get the desired result with following query which you can use to update users table. You may have to change it further if for the logic when there is tie on grades as well.

```
set @pk1 ='';
set @rn1 =1;
set @tot ='';
set @val =1;


SELECT  id,
        name,
        phase,
        phasetotal,
        denseRank
FROM
(
  SELECT  id,
          name,
          phase,
          phasetotal,
          @rn1 := if(@pk1=phase, @rn1+@val,1) as denseRank,
          @val := if(@pk1=phase, if(@tot=phasetotal, @val+1, 1),1) as value,
          @pk1 := phase,
          @tot := phasetotal     
  FROM
  (
        select users.id,users.name, points.phase, sum(points.points) 
        as phasetotal from users,points where users.id = points.userid 
        group by users.id, points.phase order by points.phase, phasetotal desc, points.grade1 desc, points.grade2 desc    
) A
) B;
```

Here's the update query

```
set @pk1 ='';
set @rn1 =1;
set @tot ='';
set @val =1;


UPDATE users u join (
SELECT  id,
        name,
        phase,
        phasetotal,
        denseRank
FROM
(
  SELECT  id,
          name,
          phase,
          phasetotal,
          @rn1 := if(@pk1=phase, @rn1+@val,1) as denseRank,
          @val := if(@pk1=phase, if(@tot=phasetotal, @val+1, 1),1) as value,
          @pk1 := phase,
          @tot := phasetotal     
  FROM
  (
        select users.id,users.name, points.phase, sum(points.points) 
        as phasetotal from users,points where users.id = points.userid 
        group by users.id, points.phase order by points.phase, phasetotal desc, points.grade1 desc, points.grade2 desc    
) A
) B ) C on u.id = C.id
   SET u.phase1 = CASE WHEN C.phase = 1 and u.phase1 = 0 THEN C.denseRank ELSE u.phase1 END,
       u.phase2 = CASE WHEN C.phase = 2 and u.phase2 = 0 THEN C.denseRank ELSE u.phase2 END;
```

Comment: i have a question how can i add to it the update query ? and set `points.phase` to `denseRank`

Comment: I have added the updated query below. check. If you have add that in left side of sqlfiddle and update is DML

Comment: i keep getting phase 1 rank for all users = 1, am i suppose to use foreach ?

Comment: not sure how you keep getting 1, here's what I did which worked for me: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/239297/1/0)

Comment: ok works, i ran it on a 1000 users but it skipped some people ranking for example if i order them by rank, the following are missing rank 49,76,92... here's what i noticed everytime there are similar values of points the next one is skipped, lets say in that case 47-48 have similar points, 49 is skipped

Comment: check the [sql fiddle updated][1] [1]: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d82584/11 isn't it ranking them wrong ? other than skipping ?

Comment: I cant help further. You need to debug this further as its getting complex. The one thing you can do is try running multiple queries and create view which can be used for other query.

Comment: dense rank being calculated wrong, cause when i do the query select only without the join i get the same result for dense rank

Comment: problem generating from this line `@rn1 := if(@pk1=stage, @rn1+@val,1) as denseRank,`

Comment: you can refer this article describing dense rank [link] http://www.folkstalk.com/2013/03/grouped-dense-rank-function-mysql-sql-query.html